# is it possible for odds ratios' or risk ratios' confidence interval to contain 1 and still be statistically significant?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, epidemiology

my understanding is that if a 95% CI for odds ratios and risk ratios contains 1 then it is not statistically significant. However I have seen in studies such as https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29484620/ where there is a table 2 showing betas and its CIs. Some CIs with the betas are statistically significant despite containing 1 in the CI. Can someone please explain this? Is this possilbe when doing multivariate linear regression?

Comment: The correct action when you need to modify a question to add information is not to delete and repost, but to click "Edit" and amend the question. Please see the tour https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour under "Improve posts by editing or commenting"

Comment: Also see discussion of how editing works in the FAQ at the meta site https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot comment on the article you cite (it is behind the firewall), you are correct regarding your interpretation of confidence intervals and what constitutes significant results. For a helpful and pragmatic article on OR and confidence intervals, see here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2938757/.